# Is there an alternative way to pass a variable as a parameter for the is_page() function in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am building my first WP plugin, it should load some JS and CSS files only on specific pages selected through a form available in the plugin Admin area. Once selected in the form, Page Title gets stored in the DB wp_options table, then the data is pulled back out in a variable named $page_selected. To load JS and CSS files only in the pages selected in the form, I wanted to use the is_page() function, passing the $page_selected variable as a parameter, doing as follows:

```
function my_custom_tooltip() {
     wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_tooltip_frontend_css', plugins_url('custom-image-tooltip/custom-image-tooltip.css') );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_tooltip_frontend_js', plugins_url('custom-image-tooltip/custom-image-tooltip.js'), array('jquery'), '', true );
} 
if (  is_page($page_selected) ) : add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_tooltip'); endif;
```

Unluckily that conditional statement does not work in my case. Is there any way to achieve the same result, matching the page selected in the form by the user with the current Page being displayed?

Comment: Hi, are you sure? Please check this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page).

Comment: What is the structure of `$page_selected`?

Comment: If I do var_dump($page_selected) after selecting "test_page_2" in the page selection form I get: string(11) "test_page_2"